# Webscrape a table with python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

### I need do a table webscrape from this site "http://www.oab.org.br/institucionalconselhofederal/quadroadvogados". Inside that are three div: Quantitativo Total,Quantitativo Genero,Quantitativo por Faixa etaria.
The code I did:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("http://www.oab.org.br/institucionalconselhofederal/quadroadvogados")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
dados = []
for body in soup.findAll('tbody'):
    dados.append(body.text)
print dados[0]
print dados[1]
print dados[2]
```

My results
dados[0]:     AC

```
                                    3.121
                                

                                    22
                                

                                    296
                                

                                    3.439
                                



                                    AL
                                

                                    10.071
                                

                                    84
                                

                                    472
                                

                                    10.627
```

dados[1]     AL

```
                                    4.527
                                

                                    5.544
                                

                                    31
                                

                                    53
                                

                                    136
                                

                                    336
                                

                                    10.627
                                



                                    AP
                                

                                    1.254
                                

                                    1.406
                                

                                    120
                                

                                    94
                                    
                                        105
                                    

                                        288
                                    

                                        3.267

dados[2] AC
                                

                                    Até 25 Anos
                                

                                    116
                                

                                    88
                                

                                    204
                                



        De 26 à 40 Anos
    

        615
    

        614
    

        1.229
    



                                    De 41 à 59 Anos
                                

                                    401
                                

                                    573
                                

                                    974
                                



                                    De 60 Anos ou Mais
                                

                                    189
                                

                                    525
                                

                                    714
                                



                                    AL
                                

                                    Até 25 Anos
                                

                                    453
                                

                                    361
                                

                                    814
                                



                                    De 26 à 40 Anos
                                

                                    2.716
                                

                                    2.616
                                

                                    5.332
                                



                                    De 41 à 59 Anos
                                

                                    954
                                

                                    1.416
                                

                                    2.370
                                



                                    De 60 Anos ou Mais
                                

                                    404
                                

                                    1.151
                                

                                    1.555
```

My question is how can I print and export this data like in the original page, formated and beautiful?
Tks for help, I'm a network admin trying start in python to learn programing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

page = requests.get("http://www.oab.org.br/institucionalconselhofederal/quadroadvogados")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
dados = {}
for k, body in enumerate(soup.findAll('tbody')):
    dados['table' + str(k)] = []
    for tr in body.find_all('tr'):
        tmp = tuple()
        th = tr.find('th')
        if th:
            th = tr.find('th').text.strip()
            tmp += (th,)
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
            tmp += (td.text.strip(),)
        dados['table' + str(k)].append(tmp)
print dados
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only scrape data, not formatting. When you save table to `excel`, then you can manually *brush* the table.
You can start with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('http://www.oab.org.br/institucionalconselhofederal/quadroadvogados')
d0=df[0]
```

but this will work as-is for 1st table only.